# debugging curl unhandled exception

Tags: c++, curl

This is a bit of a difficult issue for me to debug properly because it doesn't always happen and whether it occurs or not seems to be a matter of chance. What I'm doing is having the user set up several times. One "due date" time and several "warning" times. When these times pass, they receive a text on a provided phone number. Usually this works, but on a rare occassion, I'll get an unhandled exception from easy.c provided by curl.

```
#undef curl_easy_getinfo
CURLcode curl_easy_getinfo(struct Curl_easy *data, CURLINFO info, ...)
{
  va_list arg;
  void *paramp;
  CURLcode result;

  va_start(arg, info);
  paramp = va_arg(arg, void *);

  result = Curl_getinfo(data, info, paramp);

  va_end(arg);
  return result;
}
```

This occurs on the line "result = Curl_getinfo(data, info, paramp);"

*Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.
**data** was 0x7E8DD8. occurred*

I'm not sure why this error is occurring and it's very hard to test for it since it's occurrence is so rare and inconsistent even under identical circumstances.

I did save the callstack if that helps, but I was wondering if anyone might have a general idea of what could be causing this or if there are any tips for debugging in an inconsistent situation like this.

```
     Schedule490.exe!getinfo_long(Curl_easy * data, CURLINFO info, long * param_longp) Line 152    C
     Schedule490.exe!Curl_getinfo(Curl_easy * data, CURLINFO info, ...) Line 461    C
>    Schedule490.exe!curl_easy_getinfo(Curl_easy * data, CURLINFO info, ...) Line 844    C
     Schedule490.exe!twilio::Twilio::send_message(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > &,bool)    C++
     Schedule490.exe!Schedule::dateWarnAlert(struct tm,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)    C++
     Schedule490.exe!Schedule::nextUpdate(void)    C++
     Schedule490.exe!std::_Invoker_pmf_refwrap::_Call<void ( Schedule::*)(void),class std::reference_wrapper<class Schedule> >(void ( Schedule::*)(void),class std::reference_wrapper<class Schedule> &&)    C++
     Schedule490.exe!std::invoke<void ( Schedule::*)(void),class std::reference_wrapper<class Schedule> >(void ( Schedule::*&&)(void),class std::reference_wrapper<class Schedule> &&)    C++
     Schedule490.exe!std::_LaunchPad<class std::unique_ptr<class std::tuple<void ( Schedule::*)(void),class std::reference_wrapper<class Schedule> >,struct std::default_delete<class std::tuple<void ( Schedule::*)(void),class std::reference_wrapper<class Schedule> > > > >::_Execute<0,1>(class std::tuple<void ( Schedule::*)(void),class std::reference_wrapper<class Schedule> > &,struct std::integer_sequence<unsigned int,0,1>)    C++
     Schedule490.exe!std::_LaunchPad<class std::unique_ptr<class std::tuple<void ( Schedule::*)(void),class std::reference_wrapper<class Schedule> >,struct std::default_delete<class std::tuple<void ( Schedule::*)(void),class std::reference_wrapper<class Schedule> > > > >::_Run(class std::_LaunchPad<class std::unique_ptr<class std::tuple<void ( Schedule::*)(void),class std::reference_wrapper<class Schedule> >,struct std::default_delete<class std::tuple<void ( Schedule::*)(void),class std::reference_wrapper<class Schedule> > > > > *)    C++
     Schedule490.exe!std::_LaunchPad<class std::unique_ptr<class std::tuple<void ( Schedule::*)(void),class std::reference_wrapper<class Schedule> >,struct std::default_delete<class std::tuple<void ( Schedule::*)(void),class std::reference_wrapper<class Schedule> > > > >::_Go(void)    C++
     Schedule490.exe!std::_Pad::_Call_func(void *)    C++
     Schedule490.exe!invoke_thread_procedure(unsigned int(__stdcall*)(void *) procedure, void * const context) Line 92    C++
     Schedule490.exe!thread_start<unsigned int (__stdcall*)(void *)>(void * const parameter) Line 115    C++
     kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()    Unknown
     ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart()    Unknown
     ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()    Unknown
```

Comment: The issue is likely to be in the application code, not shown in the question.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to narrow it down because it's not giving me any hint as to what's causing it. I can't just post thousands of lines of code and say "go find the problem", can I? I'm just wondering if anyone might know probable causes so I might be able to narrow it down.